# How to show Progress dialog and dismiss on Item click

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

```
 override fun itemclick(position: Int) {
        binding.progressbar.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        binding?.barcode?.setImageBitmap(exchngeViewModel.getQrImageBitmap(qrCodeData[position], this!!.activity!!))
        showDetail(position)
        binding.progressbar.visibility=View.GONE
    }    

fun getQrImageBitmap(data: String, context: Context): Bitmap? {
        bitMap = AppUtils.TextToImageEncode(data, context, bus) 
        return this!!.bitMap
    }
```

This is my code i want to display Progress `dialog` on item click it should dismiss till that time when  `getQrImageBitmap` and showDetail function  completed but i its not working please suggest me how to achieve this how to show and hide detail on item click.Thanks!!

Comment: `its not working` what is the issue share your error log?

Comment: its no Error is coming actually it display very short time and sudden hide @R2R

Comment: yes because `getQrImageBitmap` and   `showDetail` executed means it will hide.

Comment: but that getQrImageBitmap , showDetail not completed that time i checked

Comment: Can you share whole code

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/QLD28YQZP4XYVXdSqRGjxR  this class is view https://paste.ofcode.org/39GmAvm5jK3UsT8kyAi9fzL viewmode

Answer (score 0):

Add Prorgressbar inside `showDetail()` method

```
  fun showDetail(position: Int) {
    SharedPreferenceUtils.setExchangePagePostion(this!!.activity!!, position)
    binding?.textHeader?.text = exchangeData[position]
    binding?.backButton?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding?.recyclerView?.visibility = View.GONE
    binding?.barcode?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding?.header1?.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorOrangeGray)
    binding?.exchangeButton?.visibility = View.VISIBLE


    binding.progressbar.visibility=View.GONE
}
```